# How to generate random messages from strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I've google and i can't find the exact closest thing to the function i'm seeking.
So this is the idea of the generating message on the iOS apps.
This just randomly generate random number depend on the length

```
// Generates alpha-numeric-random string
- (NSString *)genRandStringLength:(int)len {
    static NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

What i'm seeking is for the apps to generate random messages store in the array list depending on the settled time.

This is how i want it to work

```
static NSString *letters = @"Hello all","You're awesome","This is awkward","Are you sleeping?";
```

I need help to generate random messages in the string of arrays . Thank you in advance

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`.

Comment: @Popeye , it's a reminder apps i'm working on . I just need assist to enable it to generate word of advices . But why you mentioned it has nothing to do with IDE?

I've search all over google on it thou.

Comment: I have edited title of the post..

Comment: Because your question title included XCode, but it has since been edited

Comment: @SalmanZaidi , Ouh, i think i know where i went wrong. Sorry and thanks for the editing.

Comment: Also because you had the tag `xcode`. Just because you are using the `xcode IDE` doesn't mean you should be putting the tag `xcode`, which is reserved for issues with the `xcode IDE` itself. When asking a question if you are thinking about using the `xcode` tag, more than likely you shouldn't so don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a way of doing this certain task. you have to make one array with most of word instad of punting single string with all alphabet character And create random sentence. This is logical and programmatic task `xcode` not generate random word it self. you have to do some logical stuff your self.

Here i found one **github** example code please check Bellow you got idea how does you can achieve this task. Hope you getting some idea with this example.

https://github.com/dav/Objective-C-Lorem-Ipsum-Generator